# Unpickle selected objects using dill in python

Tags: python, pickle, dill

I created a pickle file using dill for my entire workspace using -

```
dill.dump_session(filename)
```

Now, instead of unpickling all the objects, I can unpickle only selected objects from this pickle file?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm the `dill` author.

I am thinking of being able to selectively filter out the objects you are pickling... but unpicking, no... no, you can't.

However, if you can think of how to index the pickled objects in the dumped session file, then feel free to open up a ticket on the `dill` GitHub page.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. I'm dumping and loading the entire session as of now.